# How to check if Process is active from a file which contains list of PID?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I have a .txt file which contains a list of PIDs and I want to write a shell script to check which of those PIDs are active.

My File.txt looks like-

```
10414
10491
10632
10636
10623
10639
```

I want to read the file line by line and check if that particular PID is active or not and if not then remove only that PID from the file.

Comment: Which states of a process would you consider active and non-active?

Comment: Active would be running in background

Answer (score 1):

Here `inputFile` is the source file containing `pids`

```
awk 'NR==FNR{p[$1]=$1;next} $2 in p{print $2}' inputFile <(ps -eaf) >inputFile.tmp && mv inputFile.tmp inputFile
```

Details:

Following will print the `ps` result for the process currently running which are also present in your file.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{p[$1]=$1;next} $2 in p' inputFile <(ps -eaf)
```

Following will create a tmp storage and create your desired file with only running pids.

```
>inputFile.tmp && mv inputFile.tmp inputFile
```

Comment: Using `cat` in a process substitution to feed Awk a regular file is pretty crazy.

Comment: @tripleee could not think of any alternate way to use `ps` and `file` both as input to `awk`. without using `pipe`

Comment: Seriously? `awk 1 <(cat file)`can be rewritten `awk 1 file`

Comment: @tripleee thanks.  ohh man. Was I was thinking.!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

for pid in $( ps -e | grep -v 'PID' | cut -f 2 -d ' ' );
do
    for _pid in $( cat $1 );
    do
        if [ $_pid = $pid ];
        then
            echo $pid
        fi
    done
done
```

Usage: `./check_if_is_active.sh list_of_pid_to_check.txt`

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor